# ExoPlayer landscape mode Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, exoplayer

I have a jetpack compose app in which there's a video player. The app is forced to portrait orientation, except for the screen/composable containing the video player. That composable is forced to landscape because I want to display the videos in landscape.

When I navigate to the page containing the video player the app correctly changes the orientation to landscape, but as soon as the video starts playing it rotates back to portrait orientation.

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Here's the relevant code for my problem.

```
@Composable
fun LockScreenOrientation(orientation: Int) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        val activity = context.findActivity() ?: return@DisposableEffect onDispose {}
        val originalOrientation = activity.requestedOrientation
        activity.requestedOrientation = orientation
        onDispose {
            // restore original orientation when view disappears
            activity.requestedOrientation = originalOrientation
        }
    }
}

fun Context.findActivity(): Activity? = when (this) {
    is Activity -> this
    is ContextWrapper -> baseContext.findActivity()
    else -> null
}

@Composable
fun VideoView() {
    val exoPlayer = remember {
        ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
            .build()
            .apply {
                setMediaItem(
                    MediaItem.Builder()
                        .apply {
                            setUri("https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4")
                            setMediaMetadata(
                                MediaMetadata.Builder()
                                    .build()
                            )
                        }
                        .build()
                )
                prepare()
                playWhenReady = true
            }
    }

    DisposableEffect(
        AndroidView(factory = {
            PlayerView(context).apply {
                player = exoPlayer
                useController = false
                layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                )
            }
        })
    ) {
        onDispose { exoPlayer.release() }
    }
}

@Composable
fun VideoScreen() {
    LockScreenOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)

    RakeVragenTheme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
            color = Color.Black
        ) {
            VideoView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I copy pasted your code to a fresh single activity project and set `VideoScreen` as the only content. The screen goes to landscape orientation as expected and stays in the landscape when the video is playing. I used a pixel 3 xl emulator running api 29

Comment: Hi @Manu, thanks for testing the code. If I run this on a Pixel 3xl emulator, the video rotates back to portrait mode so there must be something different I'm doing then. If I run this on an actual device the video rotates with the device (from portrait to landscape and back) even though the screen orientation should be locked to landscape. Any thoughts on why that might be?